# how to preserve attributes for ufunc and operator xarray operations?

Tags: python, python-xarray

Given

```
da = xr.DataArray([0], attrs={"foo": 42})
```

I can calculate (for example) the sum while preserving coordinates using

```
da.sum(keep_attrs=True)
```

however, how can I keep the attributes when applying a ufunc such as `np.sin(da)` or using operator overloading such as `1-da`?  Of course, I can simply reassign the attributes at the end of my operations, but is there any way to preserve them in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of xarray 0.11 (released 2018-11-07), you can set

```
xarray.set_options(keep_attrs=True)
```